# Google Maps API doesn't work in signed app; I created SHA1 with my keystore key

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps API doesn't work in a signed app even though I created SHA1 with my keystore key and my password like on Google's developer site. And Google Maps doesn't work. Please help me.

[image: Here is a screen shot]

Comment: sometimes it take few minutes to reflect or try to install/uninstall. only in case all information you saying are correct.

Comment: There are 30 minute since I generate my key

Comment: Personally, i create a SHA1 key with a Google Map activity template from Android Studio

Comment: as long as Package name SHA-1 certificate fingerprint are correctly inputted on API console in Credentials it should work. Check again no for the SHA-1

Comment: Are you debugging on real device or Virtual?

Comment: @UmerAsif real device with release apk

Comment: @mehmetyılmaz no idea bro. i thought. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I solved the problem by pressing the "regenerate key" button on the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

you are using developer version of sha1. you need to again generate SHA1 using command prompt after making you apk signed.Steps to regenerate SHA1 is go to cmd and give the command like below:
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore 
   "C:\Your key store path\keystores\android.jks"

go to your java in program file open java version like jre1.8.0 open bin folder and run command like above follwed by your key store path that you have generated when you generated the signed apk 
after running this command on cmd you need to provide password of signed app and your SHA1 will be gerarated.copy the sha1 and paste into console.developer with your package name within your api key.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and my issue was that I was using my keystore key -- but this is only the key used for **uploading** the app, Google has a separate key for **signing** the app.

I was able to find the key for signing in the `Google Play Console` under `Release Management > App signing > App signing certificate`.